# IDEA community edition doesn't see M2_HOME on Windows

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

These are my settings:

[image: my idea maven settings]
[image: my env vars]
[image: some more vars]
[image: And the problem itself]

Any ideas why this may happen?

Comment: Have you tried building your maven application using the Windows console?

Comment: yes, it works from console

Comment: Does it work, if you check `override` and provide the right path in the settings dialog?

Comment: I'll check a little bit later.

Comment: no, setting override doesn't help

Comment: did you happen to using a different version of mvn script in your bin folder? or did you modified the mvn script to set the M2_HOME path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IDEA cannot run maven goals with Maven 3.3.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783)

Answer (score 0):

Does it only affect the community edition?

It couldn't be a simple typo in the captialization of the drive letter? Usually Windows isn't that picky about capitalization iirc, but have you tried changing

```
c:\apache-maven-3.3.1
```

to

```
C:\apache-maven-3.3.1
```

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't help.